# Does the gibberish language Minions speak receive translations for international releases?

Tags: despicable-me, minions

The minions from the Despicable Me franchise speak a lot of indecipherable gibberish with just enough real words included to get an idea of what the minions' thoughts are. The mess of words they speak isn't just English though, I've heard what sounds like both French and Spanish in their "dialog".

Because the Minion's language is already supposed to be largely incomprehensible and because it already includes some non-English phrases I am curious to see if it receives a translation when the Despicable Me films are released for non-English-speaking audiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words that remain English in midst the gibberish are in fact translated, presumably to also convey an idea of their thoughts to the viewer. The voice actors even seem to be entirely different based on a comparison between two trailers, although having applied the same high pitch effect to their voice lines. As of whether the actual gibberish is exactly the same I'm unsure, maybe someone else can elaborate.